# Overwrite if if it exists or create if it does not

Tags: centos, vagrant, puppet

I am trying to rewrite a file using puppet with the following function.

If the file exists I still want the file to be rewrite from the source. Will this be achieved with the following method?

```
define setup_sysctl_conf( $dependence=File[$dummy_dependence_file] )
  {
        file { $name:
         path    => '/etc/sysctl.conf',
                 ensure  => present,
         mode    => 0777,
         source  => '/vagrant/files/sysctl.conf',
         require => $dependence, 
     }

  }
```

Comment: Because searching for this led me here (may be helpful to the community in the future): if you want to NOT overwrite if exists but create if it does not, use:   replace => "no",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file: /etc/sysctl.conf will already be present on your host (created by the initscripts package).

I would recommend to modify existing files with puppet using [augeas](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#augeas) instead of replacing them.

**Example** (changes net.ipv4.ip_forward to 1):

```
class sysctl_augeas_example {
  augeas{"Set net.ipv4.ip_forward to 1":
    context   => "/files",
    changes   => [
      "set etc/sysctl.conf/net.ipv4.ip_forward 1",
    ]
  }
}
include sysctl_augeas_example
```

Save this example as test.pp and run it with `puppet apply test.pp`